# call websocket open in qt

Tags: qt, websocket

i want to know QWebSocket.open function in QT
this is my qt code.
but this is not working now.

```
void MainWindow::onWatchListChanged()
{  
    m_webSocket.aboutToClose();
    m_url = QString("ws://rt.test.com/ws2/");
    qDebug() << m_url;
    m_webSocket.open(m_url);
}
```

i am using postman application for QWebScoket test.

postman has 4 tabs for websocket. `(Message, Params, Headers, Settings)`

Message has `{"channels": ["I1-23", "I1035-23"]}` in postman.

Header has `key=token, value="weirskldlfjoew"` pair

how can i connect message, header value to websocket?

current connection is disconnected.
i am going to connect for websocket and send message to websocket.

Comment: Please rewrite the text., try to improve the English, because at least I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Also, read what `aboutToClose()` is. Also check for errors from `open()`.

Comment: As a general troubleshooting tip, connect all signals to lambdas which just do debug print (signal and its parameters). That way you can understand what is happening and which signals are emitted and in which order. Also, check return values of all method calls, and print error message if you get error return!